# Discord JS Client only has itself in guild members cache

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I was trying to access a member from a guild via

```
client.guilds.cache.find((guild) => guild.id === id).members.cache.find((member) => member.user.username === name)
```

but when the bot starts up the guild only contains itself until a user sends a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable member fetch When creating the client
`client = new Client({fetchAllMembers: true}}`

Do note that calling Fetch() on a guild Will Overwrite the internal cached guild.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that you haven't enabled the `Server Members Intent`, which you can enable here:

[image: Server Members Intent]

Enabling this should allow you to fetch all members in a guild.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to a combination of both ***Ethan Snow***'s and ***Dinty***'s answers, I fixed the problem. 
First, go to the bot settings and enable server members intent,

[image]

next, add this the place where you instantiated the client

```
client = new Client({ fetchAllMembers: true }}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me :/