# Discord js, Bot can only find itself until someone else send a message

Tags: discord.js

I was trying to get all the members of a role but i can only get the bot until someone else send a message then i can see them too

here is my code

```
const matches = require("../differents-matches")

module.exports = (client) => {
    setInterval(async () => {

        /*const allmatch = await matches.
        where('_notified').exists(false).
        where('_startDate').lt(Date.now()).
        where('_endDate').gt(Date.now())

        allmatch.forEach(element => {

        })*/
        console.log(client.guilds.cache.get('1050150840813498401').roles.cache.get('1050889003110506516').members.map(m => m.user.id))
        //
    }, 5000)
}
```

i tried the solution proposed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67845626/discord-js-client-only-has-itself-in-guild-members-cache) but the problem is still here

i have all the intents needed :

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers], fetchAllMembers: true });
```

and i did activate the server member intent in the bot options, i can't find any other thing to try. If you have an idea of what is the problem please leave a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected, actually the `fetchAllMembers` client option disappeared with Discord.js v13.
You should now fetch the guild members manually:

```js
const matches = require("../differents-matches")

module.exports = (client) => {
    setInterval(async () => {

        /*const allmatch = await matches.
        where('_notified').exists(false).
        where('_startDate').lt(Date.now()).
        where('_endDate').gt(Date.now())

        allmatch.forEach(element => {

        })*/
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('1050150840813498401');
        await guild.members.fetch(); // do what fetchAllMembers previously did
        console.log(guild.roles.cache.get('1050889003110506516').members.map(m => m.user.id))
        //
    }, 5000)
}
```